# Strange kerberos logs

Tags: events, active-directory, azure-active-directory, kerberos

Recently I've discovered that some "bad user name" events were appearing in my logs console.
Theese are made by "x509n:cn=".

The thing is that the SID of those accounts are S-1-0-0 (as far as I know that means null).

I have been researching, and the best I got is this:
[image]

I'm sorry for being in Spanish, but basically you can see that there's no client address or client port.

Also, in the console log, the CN is displayed like this:

[image]

I've been researching for days and I can't get any solution or usefull information, please help me :')

Comment: If the graphical log looks like this, that means it's badly programmed and vulnerable to HTML injection. It's supposed to show the `<S>` literally (which means "Subject match" in Active Directory) – not treat it as the HTML strikethrough tag. I wonder what would happen if someone tried to `kinit '<marquee>Hello!</marquee>@YOUR.REALM'`...

Comment: Hello @user1686, the thing is that is not a web server, it's a DC.
Also, could you help me on fixing this vulnerability by giving me some advice
Thanks :')